# NextJs query params not getting the right value when dynamically changed

Tags: javascript, next.js, routeparams

i have page with default query params '?status=default'

i am trying to get the value status dan dynamically change it with button trigger

when the page is load for the first time it does get the right value which is 'default'

[image: status value]

but when i change the status with onClick button the URL behave like i wanted but the value does not change

[image: url changed but the value doesnt even though it rerender]

here is my snippet

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from 'next'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const TestURL = (props: any) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { query } = router

  function handleChangeQueryParams(status: string) {
    router.replace(router.asPath, { query: { status } })
  }

  console.count('rerender')
  console.log(query.status)

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      Index
      <button>{query.status}</button>
      <button
        onClick={() => handleChangeQueryParams('Test1')}
        className="border"
      >
        change query params
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => handleChangeQueryParams('Test2')}
        className="border"
      >
        change query params2
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

been trying to use useEffect and useState but it doesnt seems to work well, what am i missing here

```
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(query.status)
  useEffect(() => {
    setStatus(query.status)
  }, [query.status])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying different method i just found out that the problem is lies on

```
router.replace(router.asPath, { query: { status } })
```

when i changed it to

```
 router.replace({
  pathname: 'test',
  query: { status },
 })
```

it works as intended